# get data from database using php mysql using if else condtion

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from a database using the following code.

If `$type` variable contains data, I will output query one, otherwise I just show all.

```
<?php
    $type = $_GET['type'];

    $sql = '';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM package WHERE ";

    if($type>0){
        //condtion 
        $sql.= "ptype = 'domestic'";
    } else{
        //else show all
        echo $sql.= "all";
    };

    $sql.= ";";
?>
```

Comment: And, what's the problem? Did you get any errors? Where is your rest of code? And why you echo $sql.= "all"l ?

Comment: just having problem in if else part  and there is no error even variable ' $type '  has a value or not $sql.= "all"; is the ouput

Comment: Remove ; after your last bracket }

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as;

```
<?php 
$type = $_GET['type'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM package";

if($type>0){
   $sql.= " WHERE ptype = 'domestic'";
}

$sql.= ";";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

update

```
<?php 
$type = $_GET['type'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM package";

if($type>0){
   $sql.= " WHERE ptype = 'domestic'";
}

$sql.= "";
?>
```